# HTML input with decimal format 999,99

Tags: html, input, format, decimal

When I introduce 3 integer I cannot introduce nor decimal separator neither decimals until I delete some digit.

It must be in keypress and I tested with regex and everything I know aboy javascript and JQuery.

Thank you very much.

```
$('#calculator-input').keypress(function (event) {

    var $this = $(this);
    if ((event.which != 44 || $this.val().indexOf(',') != -1) &&
       ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
       (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
           event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();
    if ((event.which == 44) && (text.indexOf(',') == -1)) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf(',')).length > 3) {
                $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf(',') + 3));
            }
        }, 1);
    }

    if ((text.indexOf(',') != -1) &&
        (text.substring(text.indexOf(',')).length > 2) &&
        (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
        ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
            event.preventDefault();
    }

    var calculatorInput = $('#calculator-input').val().split(",");
    var integers = parseInt(calculatorInput[0], 10);
    var decimals = parseInt(calculatorInput[1], 10);

    if(calculatorInput[0].length >= 3) {
        return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you want to format the number in the input field. But how about this solution?

```js
document.getElementById("decimal-input").onkeyup = function() {
    var digits = this.value.match(/\d/g);
    if(digits) {
        digits = +digits.join("");
        this.value = digits.toLocaleString();
    }
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="decimal-input">
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'll recommend to use the `keyup` event but you can replace it with `keypress` event too. I haven't added the validation but try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, I need no more of three whole numbers and two decimal numbers.